# Let $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be such that $A^*B=B^*A$. Show that $\text{rank} (A,B)=n$ iff $\det(B+i A)\neq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

Does anybody know how to prove the following statement: Let $A,B\in\mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be such that $A^*B=B^*A$. Show that $\det(B+iA)\neq0$ if and only if $\operatorname{rank} (A,B)=n$. It seems to be quite simple but I am not able to finish the proof. I think that I am missing something trivial.

The direction "$\Rightarrow$" is easy: If $\det(B+iA)\neq0$, then also $\det(B^*-iA^*)\neq0$, which yields that $\ker B^*\cap\ker A^*=\{0\}$, which is equivalent to the equality $\operatorname{rank} (A,B)=n$.

But the opposite implication? Let $\operatorname{rank} (A,B)=n$ or equivalently $\ker B^*\cap\ker A^*=\{0\}$ and assume that $\det(B+iA)=0$. Then we have also $\det(B^*-iA^*)=0$, which means that there is a vector $h\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\{0\}$ such that $(B^*-iA^*)h=0$, i.e., $B^*h=iA^*h$. If $h\in\ker B^*$ then also $h\in\ker A^*$, and so $h=0$ (a contradiction). Similarly, if $h\in\ker A^*$ then also $h\in\ker B^*$, and so $h=0$ (a contradiction). It remains to get a contradiction in the case when $h$ is such that $0\neq B^*h=iA^*h$. But how to do it?? By the way, so far I did not use the fact that $A^*B=B^*A$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is not true - the matrices $A=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 2 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ and $B=\left(\begin{smallmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0\end{smallmatrix}\right)$ provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 2):

I assume hereafter that notation $M^*$ is for the *conjugate transpose* of $M$.

The main remark is that, if $A^*B=B^*A$, then :

$$(A+iB)(A+iB)^*=(A+iB)(A^*-iB^*)=AA^*+i\underbrace{(BA^*-AB^*)}_{= \ 0}+BB^*$$

Thus :

$$(A+iB)(A+iB)^*=AA^*+BB^*=\underbrace{(A \ \ B)}_C \underbrace{\binom{A^*}{B^*}}_{C^*}\tag{1}$$

(matrix $C$ is $n \times 2n$).

As a consequence of (1), $$|\det(A+iB)|^2=\det(CC^*).\tag{2}$$

Let $C=U\Sigma V^*$ be the Singular Values Decomposition (SVD) of $C$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) where $U$ ($n \times n$) and $V$ ($2n \times 2n$) are unitary. We have therefore

$$CC^*=U\Sigma\underbrace{(V^*V)}_I \Sigma^*U^*=USU^*$$

where $S:=\Sigma \Sigma^*$ ; matrices $U$ and $S$ are $n \times n$ with $$S=diag(\sigma_1^2,\sigma_2^2,\cdots,\sigma_r^2\underbrace{,0,0, \cdots}_{\text{optional}})$$

where $r=rank(S)=rank(C)=rank(CC^*)$

As a consequence, using (2), we get :

$$rank(C)=n \ \iff \ \det(CC^*) \neq 0 \ \iff \ |\det(A+iB)| \neq 0.$$

Comment: Thank you for the solution. Yes, the question was formulated with the superscript $*$ meaning the conjugate transpose. However one point in the solution is not clear to me. The original assumption is $A^*B=B^*A$, but you used the equality $AB^*=BA^*$. Is it correct? Why?

Comment: They are equivalent : it suffices to take conjugation on both sides.

Comment: I don't agree. The position of the superscript is different.

Comment: Do you agree that, for complex numbers $a^*b=b^*a$ and $ab^*=ba^*$ are two equivalent equalities (you conjugate for example the first one $(a^*b)^*=(b^*a)^*$ : and you find $a^{**}b^*=b^{**}a^*$ i.e., the second one. It is exactly the same thing for matrices.

Comment: But it is not true in general. It would mean that the product $A^*B$ is Hermitian if and only if $BA^*$ is Hermitian. But for $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\ 2 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ and  $B=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0\\0 & 0\end{pmatrix}$ we have $A^*B=B=B^*A$, while $AB^*=A\neq A^*=BA^*$. And the rank condition is satisfied...

Comment: You are perfectly right, I was wrong. Nevertheless, I think that it is not harmful for the proof I give, under the condition to replace $(A+iB)(A+iB)^*$ by $(A+iB)^*(A+iB)=(A^*-iB^*)(A+iB)=A^*A+i(BA^*-AB^*)+BB^*$

Answer (score 2):

Let $C=\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}$; it is known that $\operatorname{rank}C=\operatorname{rank}C^*C$ (proof below) and that $\operatorname{rank}C=\operatorname{rank}C^*$.

Since
$$
C^*C=\begin{bmatrix} A^* & B^* \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \end{bmatrix}=A^*A+B^*B
=(A+iB)^*(A+iB)
$$
(which follows from $A^*B=B^*A$), we are done.

Suppose $X$ is an $m\times n$ matrix; we want to prove that $\operatorname{rank}X=\operatorname{rank}X^*X$; this follows from the fact that $Xv=0$ if and only if $X^*Xv=0$ and the rank-nullity theorem. One direction is obvious; for the other one, suppose $X^*Xv=0$; then also $0=v^*X^*XV=(Xv)^*(Xv)$, so $Xv=0$. Now apply this to $X=C$.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. However one point is not clear to me. The original assumption is $A^*B=B^*A$, but you used the equality $AB^*=BA^*$. Is it correct? Why?

Comment: @MattMath Fixed

Comment: But now there is another problem. We assume that $\operatorname{rank}(A,B)=n$. Does it mean that $\operatorname{rank}\begin{pmatrix}A\\ B\end{pmatrix}=n$ or $\operatorname{rank}(A^*,B^*)=n$? I am not sure.

Comment: @MattMath I think that the question is about $\pmatrix{A\cr B}$ rather than $(A\ B)$. Or it doesn't work; at least I can't see how. Just like when a column vector is written inline with commas.

Comment: No, the problem is formulated correctly - it is about $\operatorname{rank}(A,B)=n$. If it doesn't work, then there should be a counterexample - but I didn't find it.